# 'No such file or directory' installing RTC-Tools through pip

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip

I need RTC-Tools for a homework assignment. Tried to follow [this tutorial](https://rtc-tools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html) to get it:

As it needed pip for installation, I installed it according to [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Then, in the Command Prompt, I wrote:

```bash
pip install rtc-tools
```

It started downloading, but at the end I got an error message.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\rtctools_channel_flow\\modelica\\Deltares\\ChannelFlow\\SimpleRouting\\Branches\\Internal\\KLagNonlinearityParameterDenominator.mo'
```

[Full console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecSkw.png)

I don't know how to fix it.

I also tried:

```bash
git clone https://gitlab.com/deltares/rtc-tools.git
```

That gave the same error message.

I am using Python 3.9.

Comment: The documentation for rtc-tools states that Python 3.9 is recommended. It definitely fails to install in Python 3.12. Note that 3.9 will only be updated with security fixes at this time and is likely to be EOL in the near future

Comment: Thank you. I am using Python 3.9. I initially had Python 3.12, but I uninstalled it and installed Python 3.9. Now, if I do "python --version" in cmd it says that I am using Python 3.9.